# How to access the files that are in USB device?

Tags: c#

i want through the code to access specific folder in the USB device that connected to my machine and view it's files, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at using

- [DriveType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.drivetype.aspx)
- [DriveInfo.DriveType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype.aspx)
- [DriveInfo.GetDrives Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx)
- [DriveInfo.RootDirectory Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.rootdirectory.aspx)
- [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method
  (String, SearchOption)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143327.aspx)

**EDIT**

Lets *assume* the drive letter is C

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
FileInfo[] fiFiltered = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
FileInfo[] fiFilteredAndSearchOption = di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: i didn't find there what i'm looking for, can you be more specific please?

Comment: Tell us exactly what you wish to achieve, and we can give you more specific answers.

Comment: i have disk on key connected to my machine- i want to access its content - to see the folders which inside this DOK- can i do that?

Comment: So you can see the USB in your file explorer?Do you know the drive letter, or can this change?

Comment: this can change but i know how to get it

Comment: So if you have the Drive letter, you can use the mentioned articles to retrieve information from it.

Comment: i didn't find how- all the information is about the device itself not it's content

Comment: @astander are you still there?

Answer (score 0):

Going off of Adriaan if you want to get the device you can use

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(drives[1].Name.ToString());
FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();
FileInfo[] fiFiltered = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
FileInfo[] fiFilteredAndSearchOption = di.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```